# How to break on a condition from recursion in clojure macro?

Tags: clojure

```
(defmacro block [ctx & expr]
    `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `~v]) ctx)]
         ~@expr
     ))

(defn action1 [] (print "action1") (rand-nth [true false]))
(defn action2 [] (print "action2") (rand-nth [true false]))

( block  { __blockaddrabsolute "1_1" __blockaddr "1_1"}
      ( block  {typeofparent "ummutate"  __nodeid "c21f80" __blockaddr "1_1_1"} ( action1 ))
      ( block  {__blockaddrabsolute "1_1_2" __nodeid "c60590" __blockaddr "1_1_2"} ( action2 ))
      ( block  {__blockaddrabsolute "1_1_3" __nodeid "c60595" __blockaddr "1_1_3"} ( action1 )) 
      ( block  {__blockaddrabsolute "1_1_4" __nodeid "c60596" __blockaddr "1_1_4"} ( action2 ))
 "end" )
```

I want to break the execution from macro evaluation if any of the action returns false.

Expected output :

```
action1 true
action2 true
action1 false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short-circuiting behavior you want is available through `if`/`when` forms, so we can use macros to transform a series of forms in the *body* into nested `when` forms:

```
(defmacro block [bindings & body]
  (let [whens (reduce (fn [acc elem]
                        `(when ~elem ~acc))
                      (last body)
                      (reverse (butlast body)))]
    `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `~v]) bindings)]
       ~whens)))
```

Then if we `macroexpand` your sample `block` form we get this (reformatted for readability):

```
(let* [__blockaddrabsolute "1_1" __blockaddr "1_1"]
  (when (block {typeofparent "ummutate", __nodeid "c21f80", __blockaddr "1_1_1"} (action1))
    (when (block {__blockaddrabsolute "1_1_2", __nodeid "c60590", __blockaddr "1_1_2"} (action2))
      (when (block {__blockaddrabsolute "1_1_3", __nodeid "c60595", __blockaddr "1_1_3"} (action1))
        (when (block {__blockaddrabsolute "1_1_4", __nodeid "c60596", __blockaddr "1_1_4"} (action2))
          "end")))))
```

Because your `action1`/`action2` functions return random booleans you'll get varying results, but you do get the desired short-circuiting behavior. If any of the nested forms fail the `when` test, the ultimate result will be nil.

I'd consider refactoring this by introducing a more focused, generally useful `do`-like macro that short-circuits when any of its inner forms aren't truthy, and isn't concerned with bindings at all. Then use `let` for your inner bindings:

```
(defmacro do-when [x & xs]
  (if xs
    `(when ~x (do-when ~@xs))
    `~x))

(do-when
  (let [x 1 y 2] (println "step 1") (= x (dec y)))
  (rand-nth [true false])
  "randomly successful result")
```

Comment: what if action1 and action2 are macros instead of function 
`(defmacro action1 [] \`(let [~'flag (rand-nth [true false])] (do (println (str "action1" ~'flag )) ~'flag) ))
`

Comment: @Jai that should be fine, assuming your inner macros expand to valid code. Something else I wanted to suggest is trying to think about this problem in terms of data transformations instead of imperative-style statements. This seems like it could be represented as a tree and evaluated with simple functions.